Trying to use Router with page transition in Blazor makes loading content very slow
I'm having issues with implementing page transitions in my Blazor Server (Blazor Web App template) application.
I'm using BlazorTransitionableRoute, and it works. The problem is that the page loading process is broken.
With my default Router setup, it works fine:
<CascadingBlazoredModal Class="modal">
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingBlazoredModal>

My edited Router:
<CascadingBlazoredModal Class="modal">
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                <TransitionableRoutePrimary RouteData="@routeData" ForgetStateOnTransition="true">
                    <TransitionableRouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.TransitionViewLayout)" />
                </TransitionableRoutePrimary>
                <TransitionableRouteSecondary RouteData="@routeData" ForgetStateOnTransition="true">
                    <TransitionableRouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.TransitionViewLayout)" />
                </TransitionableRouteSecondary>
            </LayoutView>
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingBlazoredModal>

With the edited Router, the page loading works differently: it loads the Layout first, and after a few seconds (until it connects to Blazor, I think?) it shows the content.
Locally, it's pretty fast, but when I publish the website, it's so slow that, for example, Lighthouse detects the Layout-only-page as a fully loaded one.
Each refresh causes that delay, not only the hard refresh.
Does someone know what's going on? I don't know if any other code is useful, if so, please write :)

Do you have a global or a per-page interactivity?

@HenkHolterman global: <Routes @rendermode="@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: true))" />
